# Preciso de explicação porque o código em C dá um erro de Segmentation fault

Tags: c, ponteiro, parâmetros, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Iniciei meus estudos de alocação dinâmica mas não estou conseguindo fazer um exemplo simples, não consegui achar o problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SUCESSO 1
#define FALHA -1

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Ponto;

void criarPonto(Ponto *ponto);
int preencherPonto(Ponto *ponto, int x, int y);

int main() {
    Ponto *ponto;
    criarPonto(ponto);
    printf("O endereco de memoria é: %d\n", ponto);
    preencherPonto(ponto, 0, 1);
    printf("Coordenada X: %d\n", (*ponto).x);
    printf("Coordenada Y: %d\n", (*ponto).y);
    return 0;
}

void criarPonto(Ponto * ponto) {
    ponto = (Ponto *) NULL;
}

int preencherPonto(Ponto *ponto, int x, int y) {
    Ponto *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(Ponto));
    if(p == NULL) {
        return FALHA;
    } else {
        p->x = x;
        p->y = y;
        ponto = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: De início, `criarPonto()` não serve de nada. `preenchePonto` não preenche o `ponto` de `main`. Se quiser conferir, é só comentar os dois `printf`s após `preencherPonto(ponto, 0, 1);`, em `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refiz de um jeito que funciona. Algumas mudanças eu fiz para ficar em um estilo mais limpo, mais padronizado, e atender a demanda de um compilador decente com proteções ligadas para evitar erros inadvertidos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SUCESSO 0
#define FALHA -1

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Ponto;

void criarPonto(Ponto **ponto) {
    (*ponto) = (Ponto *)NULL;
}

int preencherPonto(Ponto **ponto, int x, int y) {
    *ponto = malloc(sizeof(Ponto));
    if (*ponto == NULL) return FALHA;
    (*ponto)->x = x;
    (*ponto)->y = y;
    return SUCESSO;
}
int main() {
    Ponto *ponto;
    criarPonto(&ponto);
    printf("O endereco de memoria é: %p\n", (void *)ponto);
    if (preencherPonto(&ponto, 0, 1) == FALHA) return FALHA;
    printf("O endereco de memoria é: %p\n", (void *)ponto);
    printf("Coordenada X: %d\n", ponto->x);
    printf("Coordenada Y: %d\n", ponto->y);
    return SUCESSO;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zXWwP8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/oykcwvag-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/MallocSegFault.c).

O problema é que não está inicializando do jeito que deseja.

Se você quer passar um argumento por referência tem que usar uma referência para ele. Se você deseja mudar o valor por referência funciona. Se o valor que você quer mudar é a referência então a referência deve ser passada por referência, portanto deve haver um ponteiro duplo ali e tratar esse ponteiro para mexer no ponteiro mais interno, como eu fiz no código.

Claro que este código é um pouco confuso. Muito provavelmente seria melhor retornar o ponteiro em vez de passar pro referência. Em geral o ponteiro ter sido inicializado ou não já serve de código de erro.

O código criado tem pouca utilizada geral, a não ser que esteja exercitando outro conceito. O `criaPonto()` escrito nesta forma não é nada melhor que fazer direto sem a função. Claro, ela pode ser útil e ter um motivo. É um abstração para no futuro poder mudar como se cria o ponto de forma que não precisa mudar na aplicação toda. mas aí especificamente não faz nada útil.

O mesmo pode ser dito para o `preenchePOnto()`. No mínimo poderia ser uma função só. Mas esta função tem um outro problema além da já relatada, ela aloca memória sem ser óbvio que isto ocorre e escondendo esse fato fica fácil esquecer de desalocar, como de fato ocorreu. Este caso não é um problema porque o código já termina em seguida e não há consequências. Mas em um código real haverá e será mais difícil perceber o erro (já houve um em um código simples, imagina em um complexo).

Seria legal se C tivesse uma sintaxe melhor para inicializar membros de uma estrutura alocada dinamicamente, mas essa função tem pouca utilidade, e se é para preencher, então deveria só fazer isto, não alocar. Pode ser que a alocação fique na função criadora.

Assim fica melhor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SUCESSO 0
#define FALHA -1

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Ponto;

void preencherPonto(Ponto *ponto, int x, int y) {
    ponto->x = x;
    ponto->y = y;
}
int main() {
    Ponto *ponto = malloc(sizeof(Ponto));
    if (ponto == NULL) return FALHA;
    preencherPonto(ponto, 0, 1);
    printf("O endereco de memoria é: %p\n", (void *)ponto);
    printf("Coordenada X: %d\n", ponto->x);
    printf("Coordenada Y: %d\n", ponto->y);
    free(ponto);
    return SUCESSO;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ThRjEY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lektqxhe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/MallocSegFault2.c).

Mas até o preenchimento não sou muito fã de fazer assim, talvez até uma macro fosse melhor, mas não ideal.

Comment: Foi esclarecedor, eu estou realmente treinando o conceito, para algumas aulas de programação de computadores. 
Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Seu código estava acima da média do que aparece aqui.